# Выбор СУБД для проекта

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, mariadb

Решил создать сервис, который по ссылке в социальных сетях/почте выдавал бы ФИО человека, но очень сложно выбрать СУБД для данного проекта. Одни говорят, что постгрес лучше всех, потом почитаешь, а оказывается mysql более производительная. А потом почитаешь ещё и оказывается, что mariadb быстрее mysql и почти все на неё перешли. И из-за этого решил задать вопрос здесь..

Структура таблицы: ФИО, почта майлру, почта Яндекс, почта Gmail, почта Hotmail, почта Yahoo, ссылка ВКонтакте, ссылка в Одноклассниках.

Количество записей: более нескольких миллионов.
Запись будет производится почти постоянно (но только администратором или его скриптом-парсером).

Какая СУБД и движок таблицы обрабатывал бы выдачу ФИО максимально быстро по одному из полей ? (по какому именно полю понятно исходя из домена почты)

Те по сути в данном проекте есть только два sql запроса: вставить в таблицу данные (сразу в одном запросе поступают все данные, их обновлять не будем и наличие мультиаккаунтов не рассматриваем), но возможно когда-то добавим несколько новых сервисов (например почту Aol). 
И получение ФИО по одному из полей (какое именно предварительно обрабатывается исходя из домена)

Comment: А вот без разницы почти, наверное. Выборка ОДНОЙ записи по индексу - вообще тьфу, а добавление... тут скорее всё в железку упрётся.

Comment: вы на написание вопроса потеряли больше времени, нежели ваш проект может от выбора менее производительной субд

Comment: Про percona забыли. По большей части под ваши задачи без разницы, производительность скорее будет зависеть от настроек СУБД. Mysql, mariadb или percona совместимые, т.е. у вас клиентский код будет один и тот же, и вы сможете в случае чего безболезненно мигрировать, с postresql слезть будет сложнее.

Comment: @etki, ну это скорее всего так (заметив скорость обработки в 0.01 секунды в phpmyadmin даже на слабых серверах), но просто интересны мнения по данному поводу что лучше выбрать и почему

Answer (score 5):

Есть большая тройка СУБД

1. IBM DB/2
2. Oracle
3. Microsoft SQL Server

У всех троих есть маленькие сыночки/дочки типа MySQL, Oracle Express, SQL Server Express и проч.

Есть еще модные ныне NoSQL + облачные приблуды. Отличаются уровнем сервиса, API и т.д.

Несколько миллионов записей, это тьфу - ни о чем. Большие сервера нужны если требуется кластеризация на несколько серверов в разных средах и т.д.

Для вашей задачи вполне подойдет MySQL (не MyISAM), Postgress или даже Oracle Express.

Что выбрать - это как бы на цвет и вкус...

Я бы лично, рекомендовал Postgres

Comment: Но если предположим, что данных больше миллиарда, постгрес так же сохранил бы свою позицию?

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев А какая принципиальная вам разница на данном этапе? Когда размеры ваших таблиц достигнут миллиардной отметки тогда и протестируете на разных базах, и если не устроит какая то из баз то с легкостью переключитесь на новую. Тем более что вся база - это одна таблица